# How to fix it? (TypeError: Object expected : docusign api)

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I will connect the API to the default permissions.

Git: https://github.com/docusign/eg-02-react-implicit-grant

When I decrypted the file downloaded from Git for the first time, there was a slight error with aux, so I modified it by renaming it to auxs and fixing all link problems. But then encountered this problem, I wanted to fix it. Thank you.

```js
TypeError: Object expected
./src/index.js
C:/Users/benzaza/test/eg-02-react-implicit-grant-master/src/index.js:26
  23 |     sendSignEnv: sendSignEnvReducer
  24 | });
  25 | 
> 26 | const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
  27 |     applyMiddleware(thunk)
  28 | ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change to:

```
const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ) : compose;
```

I don't use `null` because it will be replaced by `compose` (you use `||`).

I don't see

> Object expected : docusign api)

but I see an error:

> composeEnhancers is not a function

Comment: Sorry, my fault, Don't use `as`, I think this is typescript, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

i see Error , Then the next thing that needs to be solved.(T-T)

```js
Failed to compile
./src/index.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/benzaza/test/eg-02-react-implicit-grant-master/src/index.js: Unexpected token, expected : (17:110)

  15 | import sendSignEnvReducer from './store/reducers/sendSignEnv';
  16 | 
> 17 | const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ as typeof compose || compose;
     |
```

Comment: You need change to `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ compose : compose`

` (condition) ? value1 : value2

Comment: Please add comment or edit question, don't add an answer about your problem